# C++/CX - GetFileAsync throws breakpoint error

Tags: c++, xml, file, storage, c++-cx

I am trying to open a xml file from my Assets folder, but unfortunately I am only able to open my xml file by using a FileOpenPicker which is not the most ideal situation when I have to constantly fetch my xml file, without disturbing the user of course.

```
FileOpenPicker^ openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker->ViewMode = PickerViewMode::List;
openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".xml"); 

task<StorageFile^>(
    openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](StorageFile^ file) {
    if (nullptr != file) {
        task<Streams::IRandomAccessStream^>(file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read)).then([this](Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream) 
        {
            IInputStream^ deInputStream = stream->GetInputStreamAt(0);
            DataReader^ reader = ref new DataReader(deInputStream);
            reader->LoadAsync(stream->Size);
            String^ strXml = reader->ReadString(stream->Size);
        });
    }
});
```

I am now trying to reconstruct this code into a code which loads up my xml file without letting the user choose. I tried the following approach:

```
String^ xmlFile = "Assets\MyXmlFile.xml";
StorageFolder^ InstallationFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;
task<StorageFile^>(
InstallationFolder->GetFileAsync(xmlFile)).then([this](StorageFile^ file) {
    if (nullptr != file) {
        task<Streams::IRandomAccessStream^>(file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read)).then([this](Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream) 
        {
            IInputStream^ deInputStream = stream->GetInputStreamAt(0);
            DataReader^ reader = ref new DataReader(deInputStream);
            reader->LoadAsync(stream->Size);
            String^ strXml = reader->ReadString(stream->Size);
            stream->FlushAsync();

        });
    }
});
```

I think I get errors at the GetFileAsync which I am not able to solve and I am asking you, the community to try and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me with one modification: the `xmlFile` string contains a backslash that needs to be escaped:

```
String^ xmlFile = "Assets\\MyXmlFile.xml";
```

Note also that if you just right-clicked "Assets" in your project and chose "Add new item", that item may have ended up in your root project folder (which is the default). If you want it to be deployed to the Assets subfolder it will need to physically live there on disk in the assets subdirectory, not just be in the Assets filter. (Unlike in C#, the C++ project "folders" are actually filters and do not reflect physical directory location.)

Comment: Thank you that worked. It loads up the data but when I launch the method multiple times, I get an error thrown. And it says the following: **The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range.** This is triggered at the place: `String^ strXml = reader->ReadString(stream->Size);`